# efficient create a list based on another list in R

Tags: r, list

Although I know how to do this in Python and Java, not that familiar with how to achieve this in R
Especially I know R is very slow in loop and dynamically grow a list is slow.

assume I have a vector(list) a<-c(1,3,4), I want to have a list b that consists of elements from the following rule, any element k from a, include `3*k-2:3*k` in the list b.

```
e.g,   
1 =>  1,2,3
3 =>  7,8,9
4 =>  10,11,12
so b <- c(1,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

now more generally, if I have a rule(function)  f(k), how to append the return to the new list?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like:

```
> unlist(lapply(c(1,3,4), function(k) (3*k-2):(3*k)))
[1]  1  2  3  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

But I don't follow your request for a more general solution.

Comment: I think you answered my follow up question already. Say I have a different function that returns multiple elements and I want to apply this function to each element in the original list, so I should call this function inside your defined "function".

Comment: @Jin Makes sense. Yes, that's what you could do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, for variety.

```
as.vector(mapply(`:`, 3*a-2, 3*a))
# [1]  1  2  3  7  8  9 10 11 12
```